# Can you use the same variable twice in a parameterized query and would there be a speed advantage to it?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Can I have a query like

```
"INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3); INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (@val2, @val3)"
```

One, does doing a parameterized query in VB.NET accept duplicate variables, and two, would doing this offer any sort of a speed boost? I wanted to use it as opposed to doing two different parameterized inserts. And yes, before you mention anything about it, a stored procedure is not an option here. I won't go into why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Lesser variables would be a plus but if they are in small numbers, there won't my **much difference(noticeable)** in the performance/memory usage.

Comment: There are about 20 variables that are reused a lot across three tables, so it will help a bit. Sometimes there are periods where there are a lot of writes, so I'd like to make it more efficient where I can

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Take a look at this it might help http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3834501/Parameterized-Queries.htm

:)